# SQL Server _ Cursor in Dynamic SQL and UPDATE CASE WHEN THEN

Tags: sql-server, dynamic-sql, cursors

I would like to extract the rows that meet the condition in the CASE WHEN condition and put them in the updated table. But the trick is to create a new row every time the condition is met in one of the two tables.

```
drop table if exists [MyTable]
drop table if exists [BICHATP]
drop table if exists [AFUP]


CREATE TABLE [AFUP]
(
    [TVF] nvarchar(10),
    [RPPS] nvarchar(10)
);

CREATE TABLE [BICHATP]
(
    [TVF] nvarchar(10),
    [RPPS] nvarchar(10)
);
INSERT INTO [AFUP] ([TVF], [RPPS]) VALUES
    ('M006', '1010'), ('M054','1000'), ('M015', '1009');

INSERT INTO [BICHATP] ([TVF], [RPPS]) VALUES
    ('M000', '1101'), ('M090','1001'), ('M012', '1023');

CREATE TABLE [MyTable]
(
    [Tabs] nvarchar(100),
    [Check_column] nvarchar(10)
);

INSERT INTO [MyTable] ([Tabs]) VALUES
    ('AFUP'), ('BICHATP');


DECLARE @cmd nvarchar(max);
DECLARE @Tabs nvarchar(10);

DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR
    SELECT [Tabs] FROM [MyTable];

OPEN cur1;

FETCH NEXT FROM cur1 INTO @Tabs
WHILE(@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN
    SET @cmd = 'update [MyTable]
                set [Check_column] = case when NOT EXISTS
                    (SELECT * FROM ' + @Tabs + ' where
                    [TVF] = ''M006'' or [RPPS] = ''1009'')
                    then ''OK''
                         else ''FAILED''
                    end
               from ' + @Tabs + ' WHERE [MyTable].Tabs = ''' + @Tabs + '''';

               print @cmd
    EXEC sp_executesql @cmd;

    FETCH NEXT FROM cur1 INTO @Tabs
END

CLOSE cur1;
DEALLOCATE cur1;
```

Tables:

```
   Index      AFUP            BICHATP
 --------|------------     ------------
    1    | M006 | 1010      M000 | 1101
    2    | M054 | 1000      M090 | 1001
    3    | M015 | 1009      M012 | 1023
```

Expected Result :
select * from MyTable

```
Sheet Name |   TVF   |     RPPS  |      Cell Index      | Check result
------------------------------------------------------------------------
   UFAP    |  M006   |           |         1            | FAILED
   UFAP    |         |   1009    |         3            | FAILED
BICHATP    |         |           |                      | OK
```

Answer (score 1):

Your UPDATE sentence is not correct, you should use the form:

```
UPDATE tableA
SET    Field = CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT ....
                                 FROM   <DynamicTableName)
                                 WHERE  CONDITIONS)
               THEN 'FAILED' ELSE 'OK' END
WHERE Field2 = <DynamicTableName>
```

```
DECLARE @cmd nvarchar(max);
DECLARE @Tabs nvarchar(10);

DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR
    SELECT [Tabs] FROM [MyTable];

OPEN cur1;

FETCH NEXT FROM cur1 INTO @Tabs
WHILE(@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN
    SET @cmd = 'update [MyTable]
                set [Check_column] = 
                    case when exists(select 1
                                     from   ' + @Tabs
                                  + ' where left([TVF],4) = ''M006'' or left([RPPS],4) = ''1009'')' 
                 + ' then ''FAILED'' else ''OK'' end'             
               + ' where [Tabs] = ''' + @Tabs + '''';

    print @cmd
    EXEC sp_executesql @cmd;

    FETCH NEXT FROM cur1 INTO @Tabs
END

CLOSE cur1;
DEALLOCATE cur1;

select * from mytable;
```

```
Tabs    | Check_column
:------ | :-----------
AFUP    | FAILED      
BICHATP | OK
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=bc04feeefc0e206bbea358e187d54de4)*